# Is it possible to add two textbox fields in a PDF with the same name using Aspose.Pdf?

Tags: c#, pdf, aspose, aspose.pdf

Is it possible to add two textbox fields in a PDF with the same name using Aspose.Pdf?

The following code will automatically change the field name from what I designate by adding a incremented number to the end of the name for each field with the same name after the first one.

```
    public static void AddFields(string filePathIn, string filePathOut, List<Models.Pdf.FieldModel> fields)
    {
        var lic = new License();
        lic.SetLicense("Aspose.Total.lic");

        FormEditor formEditor = new FormEditor();
        formEditor.BindPdf(filePathIn);

        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            foreach (var instance in field.Instances)
            {
                var llx = instance.Left;
                var lly = instance.Bottom;
                var urx = instance.Left + instance.Width;
                var ury = instance.Bottom + instance.Height;
                formEditor.AddField(field.FieldType, field.Name, field.Value, instance.PageNumber, llx, lly, urx, ury);
            }
        }

        formEditor.Save(filePathOut);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Aspose.Pdf for .NET supports to add multiple textbox fields in PDF using using AddFieldAppearance() method as following.

```
Document doc = new Document(myDir + "HelloWorld.pdf");
Aspose.Pdf.Forms.TextBoxField textBoxField = new Aspose.Pdf.Forms.TextBoxField(doc, new Aspose.Pdf.Rectangle(100, 500, 175, 525));
//create partial Name
textBoxField.PartialName = "textBox";
//add field to the document
doc.Form.Add(textBoxField, 1);
//Add annotations of the added field
doc.Form.AddFieldAppearance(textBoxField, 1, new Aspose.Pdf.Rectangle(100, 625, 175, 650));
doc.Save(myDir + "MultipleFields.pdf");
```

I am Tilal Ahmad, developer evangelist at Aspose.